How do I configure Kafka SCRAM users and user quotas using REST API?
I'm maintaining some Confluent Community Kafka clusters, and I am mostly using a combination of manual CLI and Ansible together with the supplied Kafka CLI tools to do things like create new users, configure quotas and ACLs. However, I would like to switch to using the REST API as much as possible, to avoid all the overhead and mess of creating commands and running them via Ansible locally on a broker.
I have set up a REST Proxy node that works, but I am now finding that the "configs" API endpoint in the REST Proxy doesn't actually match the functionality of the "kafka-configs" CLI tool. The tool seems to have additional functions relating to users and quotas that I can find no trace of in the API documentation.
Examples of commands I would like to be able to run via the REST API instead:
/usr/bin/kafka-configs
  --bootstrap-server <server>:9094 --command-config kafka-cli.properties
  --entity-type users
  --entity-name "foobar"
  --alter
  --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-256=[password=SECRET],SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=SECRET]'

/usr/bin/kafka-configs
  --bootstrap-server <server>:9094 --command-config kafka-cli.properties
  --entity-type users
  --entity-name "foobar"
  --alter
  --add-config producer_byte_rate=256000

Is this even possible? If so, how?
Note that we don't have the licensed Confluent Server platform, only the unlicensed Community version. Also, the question is not about authenticating with SASL SCRAM, that part is already working fine.
I have tried running calls to the configs API and I have read the API documentation, but there is no mention of anything corresponding to the --entity-type users portion of the CLI tool's arguments.
